# How can i integrate a chat window popup in my react project?

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io, chat

I need an chat component in react which i can easily integrate in my web application by which when i click on a user a chat popup window should open through which they both can chat together.

Comment: If you have to insert a third-party chat-snippet, then add it in index.html, nothing to do with react.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the wording of your question, I will assume that you know how to build the component itself. If not, you can always learn or use something ready-made with a chat-popup such as:

[react-chat-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chat-window)

If your question is then only how to open the component in a new window, you would need to set up a route to your component, probably using a routing library like react-router-dom, set up a route:

```
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom'

<Route path='/chat' component={Chat}/>
```

And where you would like to open up the chat, use some js, for example:

```
<button onClick={() => window.open(localhost:3000/chat)}>
Click to open chat
</button>
```

Where `window.open(url)` is a function telling the browser to open a link in a new window.

Comment: is react-chat-elements only for react native i want to use it in my website

Comment: Edited with a reactjs library.